# Getting last records for each user based on timestamp in indexedDB

Tags: indexeddb

We have a customers table which stores the `customer` id, the `item` last purchased and the timestamp `ts`.

This is how objectstore was created

```
var mos = db.createObjectStore("customers", { autoIncrement : true });
mos.createIndex("purchases", ["customer", "item", "ts"], { unique: false });
```

I like to get the last item purchased by each customer. Currently we are reading the entire table and taking each unique entry based on customer id `customer` and timestamp `ts`. However, we now have larger number of customers now and it is slow.

Is there any way to get just the latest entry for each `customer` based on the timestamp `ts`

Let me know if you need more information

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Create an index on customer id and timestamp. Open a cursor over the index with a specific customer id and without specifying the timestamp, or by specifying a timestamp sentinel value that constitutes a valid boundary. When opening the cursor, specify direction `prev`.